# How many concurrent connections can support a Jelastic node?

Tags: multiplayer, jelastic, smartfoxserver

I'm using Jelastic and smartfoxserver 2x for a multiplayer server. I want to know if there is a limit to the concurrent tcp socket connections.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit of 50 TCP connections if you haven't public IP.